# What is the worst case target number for binary search?

Tags: binary-search

For simplicity, let's say the number is between 1 and n. Is there a generic formula that gives us the number that results in the maximum number of binary search iterations?

I always have to write things about by hand, but I feel there should be an analytical form that is a function of `n`.

Comment: How I'd attack it: Write out a sample tree and look at the numbers that end up in the bottom row. My first thought is that half the nodes will be on the lowest layer of the tree, and half will be in some higher layer. There's probably a pattern to the numbers in the bottom row. What is it? It'll be something that applies to half of all numbers. Are they all even/odd? Or maybe they share some property in their base-2 representation?

Comment: @JohnKugelman The worst case is where the number of nodes get continuously halved until there is 1 node left. I guess this could occur for several target numbers though so maybe it would be difficult to find a function that returns all of these numbers

Comment: (cont'd) Start with a full tree, so one with 8, 16, or 32 nodes. If you can figure out a pattern there then you can look at incomplete trees whose sizes aren't powers of 2.